Open sounding chorus on tight synth
I want to emulate the gliding synth that you here in Dune Part 2 clip linked here when the Harkonnens levitate. It sounds like a really filtered out saw wave with some chorus, but I'm not sure what the sound is "supposed" to be. That is, do I filter alongside the chorus effect or are there other effects as well?

Sorry, but finding how to emulate a "sound" is really not in the scope of this website: there are virtually infinite ways to imitate a timbre: not only we don't know nothing about your possible equipment (VST? HW synth? Analog or digital? etc.), but we don't even know nor understand how accurate you want it to be. For what we know, you could be satisfied with an electric guitar and a couple of pedals, a quite expensive analog synth, adding some unknown filter applied to your own voice, or whatever. Did you actually try to do that? Then show your attempts and explain how you achieved them.

@ojs I get your point, and partially agree. Still, the OP is asking a question that is, in my opinion, excessively broad, just like many others that I believe wouldn't be accepted anyway: "emulate the [...] synth" wouldn't be that different than asking about "emulate the sound of the voice with an instrument". What instrument? The OP mentions using a saw wave, but many different synths produce quite different sounds even based on the simple concept of "saw wave", depending on their hardware (or software) implementation. Even emulation of physical analog synths doesn't get identical results.

I view to reopen. My reading of the question is that it's asking how a particular effect is achieved when programming a synth and uses a specific song as an example of that synth. It reads like a "how do I make this synth" question, but the difference for me is that the question is specific about which part of the sound is being asked about. And that moves it out of transcription territory.

@ojs English is my native language but I have a programming background so used "emulate" sleepily. Nonetheless, I agree the question as phrased too broadly. I'll try to edit it in a while, but essentially I know that there is an electric guitar layer with modulating distortion iirc, and a synthesized brass layer. But I don't know how the reverbing brass layer is made to sound that synthetic-sounding. So I was essentially asking how the effect of synthesis is added on the brass, if it indeed is a real brass layer.

@musicamante Yep I agree it is too broad, I'll edit it. And sorry for the weird phrasing because I have a strange background with my work (English is my native language) and I was trying to replicate that effect, not produce exactly that sound I mentioned in the clip. The exact sound in itself is prob a synthesized electric guitar layered with a cello and a brass layer with lots of reverb like Andy pointed out, but I was trying to replicate that effect with a different synth layer, which I can't seem to do. But thanks anyway.

I got a good laugh out of people being unfamiliar with the word "emulate"; maybe the issue is that "synth" isn't their native language! Meanwhile I'ma double down on the claim that that toothy "saw wave" sound is a close-miced bowed string bass, maybe with a bit of high-pass to accentuate the bow sound.

@AndyBonner Yeah but I don't want to argue against peeps on SE lol. But yeah that feels right, I'm trying to "emulate" the sound, will tell you if it goes like I think :)

I was able to get into the same ballpark by using granular synthesis on a distorted guitar.  Granulator III with some spread in mono mode with portamento worked pretty well.  The choice of guitar sound is going to be a big factor here.
Setting up the right space for this kind of sound is going to be important too.  This sound is full of reverb and is really big, which would work fine for a film soundtrack, but your milage will vary!
There are also a lot of other layers to the sound, which makes it difficult to tease apart.
Hopefully that's helpful.

Hans Zimmer is known for using U-he synthesizer plugins. He has his own version of Zebra 2. You can try using this
free plugin from U-He. It's the beta version of the new Zebra.

I do have Zebralette 3, but I was asking how the effects themselves were made more than the actual synth or the actual processing itself.

Lots of reverb and something like Brauer Motion.
